# Show that $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{1+\tanh x\over (1+\tan x)^2}\mathrm dx=(1/10+1/100)(6+1/6)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Observing this integral $(1)$; yield a rational closed form?

> $$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{1+\tanh x\over (1+\tan x)^2}\mathrm dx=(1/10+1/100)(6+1/6)\tag1$$

**Making an attempt:**

It is very difficult to even make and attempt here.

Note that

$$1+\tanh x={2e^{2x}\over e^{2x}+1}$$
**How can we prove $(1)?$**

Comment: The RHS of $(1)$ is $0.678333333\ldots$ but the LHS is $0.67833284341866\ldots$. $(1)$ does not hold.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, is right. It seemed a strange equality to be honest.

Comment: Indeed, consider these calculations from wolfram alpha: [LHS](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2Btanh(x))%2F(1%2Btan(x))%5E2+from+0+to+pi%2F2+10+digits) and [RHS](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F10+%2B+1%2F100)(6%2B1%2F6)).